# Buying alcohol duty free under 21 when departing the US?

Tags: usa, legal, alcohol, duty-free, age-limits

Is it legal/possible to purchase alcohol as duty free upon departure from the US, having attained the drinking age in the destination country but not in the US?

It seems like even though you are buying it in the US, since it's for exclusive use in another country it should be allowed.....but I can see it being illegal to buy anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is the sale that is illegal. So it doesn't matter where you plan on consuming it. The act of selling it is what is forbidden for those under 21.